# ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to Models.EditTextMonitor

Tags: java, android, android-edittext, classcastexception

I have class EditTextMonitor in Models package, example:

```
public class EditTextMonitor extends EditText{
private final Context mcontext; // Just the constructors to create a new EditText...

public EditTextMonitor(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.mcontext = context;
}

public EditTextMonitor(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.mcontext = context;
}

public EditTextMonitor(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.mcontext = context;
}


@Override
public boolean onTextContextMenuItem(int id) {
    // Do your thing:
    boolean consumed = super.onTextContextMenuItem(id);
    // React:
    switch (id){
        case android.R.id.copy:
            onTextCopy();
        case android.R.id.paste:
            onTextCopy();
    }
    return consumed;
}
public void onTextCopy(){
    ((TextEditorActivity)mcontext).startAmode();
}
}
```

In my java class: EditTextMonitor editor = (EditTextMonitor) findViewById(R.id.texteditor);

In xml view file it`s defined:

```
<Models.EditTextMonitor
        android:id="@+id/texteditor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="top"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textAllCaps="false" />
```

But i have error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 

ComponentInfo{com.atompark.atompark_sms/com.atompark.atompark_sms.TextEditorActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to Models.EditTextMonitor
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2413)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2471)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:175)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1308)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5603)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.EditText cannot be cast to Models.EditTextMonitor
at com.atompark.atompark_sms.TextEditorActivity.prepereInterface(TextEditorActivity.java:194)
at com.atompark.atompark_sms.TextEditorActivity.onCreate(TextEditorActivity.java:97)
...
```

I have this error only on tablet devices.

Comment: Then you probably did not change all your layouts to use this class. Make sure that you do not have a layout in another resource set (e.g., `layout/sw600dp/`) that has an `EditText` here.

Comment: in all my layout xml files, using Models.EditTextMonitor

Comment: May be you need to use complete package name instead of just Models.EditTextMonitor  like yourpackagename.Models.EditTextMonitor.

Comment: EditTextMonitor is define in a package name "Models" ?

Comment: Yes EditTextMonitor defined in package name "Models". Not in com.atompark.atompark_sms

Answer (score 0):

In xml use class name with proper package name as for your TextEditorActivity

```
com.atompark.atompark_sms.TextEditorActivity
```